# Android : what Strategics or steps to connect my android app to SQL server

Tags: android, sql-server

Friends

Any one can tell me  ,, what Strategics or steps to connect my android app to SQL server ??

i want to developer android app , this app connected to Sql server direct , and whats best choices to do that ???

thanks for help

Comment: consider make a `webservice` that connect to the SQL server and provide android client with data .

Comment: are you using C# from the server side?

Comment: yes ,, but some tutorial just keeping say < must use web server PHP to make bridge between my app and database. another Strategics to do that

Answer (score 2):

You could use a webservice to provide service orientated architecture (SOA).

For example you may have a database with a PHP/Java/.Net application connected to it. When a mobile device makes a web request to this application, it returns data to the device.

The data returned could be in a choice of formats such as json or xml. Personally I prefer json if mobile devices are involved as the footprint from json is smaller than xml due to its characteristics. However that said, should you need meta data in the response then xml maybe more useful.

There are many tutorials on this and libraries to help deserialise responses (GSON from google is good when Json is involved), therefore I am not going to reinvent the wheel when others before me have explained this before and probably better.

Finally; the use of a webservice allows for multiple platforms to communicate with your database (and other services you offer) and allows for any 'heavylifting' to be done on a server rather than a mobile device.

Comment: why some developer do not Prefer direct connection between android app and SQL server database , WHY ???

Answer (score 0):

From your comments to Graham Smith's answer, I understand you prefer to connect to SQL Server directly, without an explicit webservice or other communication layer in between.

You have to understand: android devices are usually *mobile*, so an indirect connection that doesn't require the android device to be in the same network as the SQL Server (including the security horrors that brings along in an enterprise environment) is usually preferred.

Back to the actual question: you can us JDBC to access SQL Server from Android. Either use Microsoft's own [JDBC Driver for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724), or use the Open Source [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) . The latter seemingly solves some connection problems some peole seem to be having with the Microsoft driver.

Comment: thanks for all , i want to know specifically in security, why dose not like direct connection , why web server is better ?